Сайт не подстраивает позицию элементов в зависимости от размера окна
Я написал на Javascript код который берет из json файла данные по кабинетам и расставляет их на сайте по координатам x, y, но проблема в том что при изменении размера окна браузера или на телефоне, кабинеты остаются на том же месте и не меняют положение в зависимости от размера окна. Что делать?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Кабинетs</title>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

    <script src="../../scripts/options.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="https://oksei.ru/public/img/logo.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainTitle">
        <a href="../../index.html"><img src="https://oksei.ru/public/img/logo.png" style="height:60px; width: auto; margin-left: 10px; padding: 10px;"></a>
        <h1 style="align-self: left; margin-left: 10px; padding: 5px;">ГАПОУ "ОКЭИ" Кабинеты</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="gridBox">
        <div class="gridComponent">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div class="floor-menu">
                <button class="floor-btn" data-floor="1">Этаж 1</button>
                <button class="floor-btn" data-floor="2">Этаж 2</button>
                <button class="floor-btn" data-floor="3">Этаж 3</button>
                <button class="floor-btn" data-floor="4">Этаж 4</button>
                <!-- Добавьте кнопки для других этажей по аналогии -->
            </div>
            
    <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div> <!-- Элемент для отображения подсказки -->
    <script src="cabscript.js"></script>
        <!--<div class="left-col">
            <div class="gridComponent">
                
            </div>
            <div class="gridComponent">
                
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="right-col gridComponent">
        </div>-->
    </div>
</body>

CSS:
.gridBox {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  
    height: 85vh;     
}

.gridComponent {
    height: 100%;
}

.gridComponent:hover {
    transform: none;
}

.left-col .gridComponent {
    height: 50%;
}

.left-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 33.3%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.right-col {
    width: 66.6%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.room {
    max-width: 60px; /* Изменяем ширину комнаты на 8% от ширины экрана при ширине экрана до 768px */
    max-height: 60px; /* Также изменяем высоту комнаты */
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer; /* Добавляем указатель при наведении */
}


@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
    .room {
        width: 5%; 
        height: 7%;
    }
    .stream-room {
        width: 10%;
        height: 14%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .room {
        width: 6%; 
        height: 8%;
    }
    .stream-room {
        width: 12%;
        height: 16%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .room {
        width: 8%; 
        height: 10%; 
    }
    .stream-room {
        width: 16%;
        height: 20%;
    }
}
.computer-room {
    border-color: blue;
}
.stream-room {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 140px;
}

.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none; 
}

.floor-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

/* Определяем стили для всех кнопок */
.floor-btn {
    background-color: #33333300;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.233);
    font-size: x-large;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 6px; /* добавляем округление углов */
}

/* Определяем стили для кнопок при наведении */
.floor-btn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}


/* Определяем дополнительные стили для активной кнопки */
.floor-btn.active {
    background-color: rgba(65, 76, 233, 0.548); /* изменяем цвет активной кнопки */
    font-size: xx-large; /* изменяем размер шрифта при активации */
    color: white; /* изменяем цвет текста */
}

JavaScript:
 let classrooms_ = void 0;

async function LoadCabinetsData()
{
    const dataShit = await fetch("./myAss.json");
    const fuck = await dataShit.json();
    return fuck["floor"];
}

async function drawCabinets(floor) {

    if(classrooms_ === undefined)
    {
        console.log("Loading Classroms");
        classrooms_ = await LoadCabinetsData();
    }

    let classrooms = classrooms_[floor-1];

    var map = document.getElementById('map');
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

    console.log(classrooms)

    if(classrooms !== undefined)
    {
        classrooms.forEach(function(classroom) {
            var room = document.createElement('div');
            room.className = 'room';
            room.style.left = classroom.location[0] + 'px';
            room.style.top = classroom.location[1] + 'px';
            room.style.backgroundColor = getColor(classroom.students, classroom.capacity);
            room.innerText = classroom.cabinet;
            if (classroom.type === 'Компьютерный') {
                room.classList.add('computer-room');
            }
            if (classroom.type === 'Поточный') {
                room.classList.add('stream-room');
            }
            room.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
                tooltip.innerHTML = `Кабинет №${classroom.cabinet}<br>Тип: ${classroom.type}<br>Вместимость: ${classroom.capacity}<br>Сейчас в кабинете: ${classroom.students} студентов<br>Группы: ${classroom.groups.join(', ')}`;
                tooltip.style.left = (classroom.location[0] + 40) + 'px';
                tooltip.style.top = (classroom.location[1] - 20) + 'px';
                tooltip.style.display = 'block';
            });
            room.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
                tooltip.style.display = 'none';
            });
            map.appendChild(room);
        });
    }
    function getColor(students, capacity) {
        var percentage = (students / capacity) * 100;
        if (percentage < 25) {
            return 'green';
        } else if (percentage < 50) {
            return 'lightgreen';
        } else if (percentage < 75) {
            return 'yellow';
        } else if (percentage < 90) {
            return 'orange';
        } else {
            return 'red';
        }
    }

}

drawCabinets(1);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.floor-btn');
    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var floorNumber = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-floor'));
            //console.log(floorNumber)
            changeFloor(floorNumber);
        });
    });
    changeFloor(1);
});

function changeFloor(floorNumber) {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.floor-btn');
    buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.classList.remove('active'); // Убираем класс active у всех кнопок
    });
    var button = document.querySelector('.floor-btn[data-floor="' + floorNumber + '"]');
    button.classList.add('active'); // Добавляем класс active к нажатой кнопке

    while (map.firstChild) {
        map.removeChild(map.lastChild);
    }
    drawCabinets(floorNumber);
}


позиционировать в процентах или добавить событие resize и пересчитывать позиции

@Arbery
Ну я пытался добавить window.addEventListener("resize", function() {     console.log("Resize Event") }); Но ничего не происходит
